# WebApplicationContext is always null in a spring boot test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

My test class looks like this

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class sampleClassTest{

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;
}

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();

}
```

In the setup method, wac is always null. From spring boot documentation, `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.MOCK)` always created a mock `WebapplicaitonContext`.

So I would expect it get autowired in the code above which doesn't happen.

Can someone tell me how to go about creating a `webapplicationContext` in this case so that it's not null like in my case ?

## UPDATE

I am running spring boot tests invoking them from a class with springboot annotation.

Both test (springboottest) and calling class (springboot) application are in the same spring boot project under `src/main/java`.

I have nothing under `src/main/test`. I have done in this way because if classes from `src/main/java` want to call a test class then, it isn't really a test class.

Now, the problem is that I can't use `runWith(SpringRunner.class)` in springbootTest class. If I did that to get a mock `webApplicationContext` then, it gives me this error:

```
 javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
```

I am not sure how to do about this.

Comment: Add `@WebAppContext` to the test case. However you can also simply `@Autowire` the `MockMvc` class with Spring Boot ( you don't need to create it manually).

Comment: I still need a webApplicationContext to register beans in to. So my main problem is to get a webApplicationContext.

Answer (score 1):

To use `@SpringBootTest` you need to use Spring Framework's test runner. Annotate your test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

Comment: Actually, I am writing some acceptance tests for my application. So I have a class decorated with SpringBootapplication annotation which internally calls a class decorated with springboottest annotation which is the code that I have already pasted above. In this scenario,if I used Runwith(SpringRunner.class), i get the error javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication

Comment: That is obviously not going to work. `@SpringBootTest` is for unit test not for use on arbitrary classes, the same for the `@Before` that is for use with jUnit and not on arbitrary classes. Why wouldn't you be able to create a test as a test and use that instead of what you are trying to build now...

Comment: I am trying to run some acceptance tests from springboot main class using JUnitCore class. Looks like my approach of using springbootTest class in this case won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is struggling with this issue in 2022 - please keep my defined precondions in mind. If you are using @SpringBootTest with defined port and constructor auto-wiring of the test class, the application context might be null.

It seems that the constructor dependency injection is eager and the cache aware context delegate of Spring is searching for a web application context which is no available yet. If you use field auto-wiring your test might run in a deterministic manner.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever is facing this issue, make sure your spring boot starter parent version is compatible with spring cloud version in pom.xml

I was facing same issue, i resolved it by doing same.